# What is difference between operating wave function with operator of an observable and measuring for an observable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, hilbert-space, observables

People say operator of an observable helps in measuring for an observable. We also know that measuring leads to collapse of wave function. But operator on wave function gives a number times same wave function (which of course is not a collapsed wave function!). All intuitions I made about operator, wave function, measures, collapse are all seeming to be inconsistent. If operator doesn't collapse a wave function then what it is for. Is it just for calculating expectation value of observable. What in physical sense it is?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Your post contains a few misunderstandings about the way the measurement process works in the collapsing wave function picture - I'd think it useful for you to read that up again ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different points/distinctions that need to be made here.
1. The expectancy value when measuring an observable to which the operator $A$ can be assigned is $\langle A \rangle = \langle \Phi | A | \Phi \rangle$ for a system described by a wavefunction $|\Phi\rangle$.
2. If the value $a$ is measured, the collapse of the wavefunction means that we project $ |\Phi\rangle$ onto the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $a$ of the operator, i.e., the wavefunction is changed.
3. $A | \Phi \rangle = a | \Phi \rangle$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ holds only if $| \Phi \rangle$ is an eigenfunction of the operator $A$. In general, $A | \Phi \rangle$ does not need to be proportional to $| \Phi \rangle$ but can be a different wavefunction.
4. An operator $A$ determines the possible values of its measurement variable by its eigenvalues and determines the possible wavefunctions after it has been measured by its eigenstates/eigenspaces.
5. Applying an operator to a wavefunction does not describe the measurement process.

Comment: Thank u so much. Its all clear now in those points. Just wanted to make sure that does it mean if operator Â acts on a general wave function then resultant would be a wave function which would be a linear combination of several eigenfunctions of Â with associated eigenvalues? Also is all this business of operator just a mathematical trick with no physically observable analogue?

Comment: If I am not completely mistaken, the spectral theorem tells us that the operator is basically a sum/integral over the projections on the eigenspaces multiplied by their eigenvalues, so I think the answer to your first question is yes. To your second question - physically observable is the spectrum of the operator as the possible measurement outcomes, so I'd say it is more than a mathematical trick.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in pointing out that operating with an operator on a wavefunction gives a number times the wavefunction (assuming that it is indeed an eigenfunction of the said operator). Measuring the observable collapses the wavefunction. *How* a wavefunction collapses is still an open question in Quantum Physics. The job of the operator is to find out the possible eigenvalues of the wavefunction. [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4325) paper might help you with the progress that has been done in solving that open problem.

Comment: Just a side note here. Acting with an operator on a wavefunction does not constitute a measurement right? Also tell me if the question says 'what is the value of the measurement of an operator say A on a wavefunction $\psi$, then i find its expectation value; then does finding the expectation value mean measurement which in turn means collapse of the   wavefunction? Or is measurement just a vague physical process which messes with the instruments and find the expectation value is a separate mathematical calculation on paper that has nothing to do with measurement??

Comment: That s a doubt I had as well. What I believe by 'measurement' they precisely mean finding out some definite quantitive parameters which potentially define state of a system and hence constitute 'psi'. Various systems with different 'psi' might turn out to be having same expectation value. I'm not sure though.